# python imaplib search with multiple criteria

Tags: python, search, imaplib

I'm trying to use the search function and am running into an issue. I can download all attachments from a gmail account and sort them according to the file extension. I have all of that code working right except when I add extra criteria to the search. Originally the search criteria was only for UNSEEN emails, which works and then flags the email as seen and moves it to the trash. I then decided to add to it. Here is the example:
original:

```
resp, items = m.search (None, 'UNSEEN')
```

new:

```
resp, items = m.search (None, '(FROM "email" SUBJECT "some text")', 'UNSEEN')
```

It results with the emails moved to the trash, still unread and none of the attachments downloaded. Anyone have any idea what I may be doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Your search criteria is wrong I guess.use some thing like '(FROM "email" SUBJECT "some text" UNSEEN)'

Comment: I forgot all about this JithPS. I cant remember what I did about this but thanks!

Answer (score 8):

To build on JithPS comment the right syntax is like this:

```
result, data = mail.search(None,'(FROM "email" SUBJECT "the subject" UNSEEN)')
```

The clauses are passed with capital letters and the criteria within quotes.